# Adding nodes to a line by interval in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am a MapBasic beginner, and I just want a simple .mbx or tool that can add nodes to a line by interval (say every 50m). I don't really need it to have a start point or end point (or maybe it is necessary to have that for the code to work, not a problem). Just maybe a dialog box that lets me bring in the line table and specify my interval, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the free tool ToolBox from Routeware.

You can find it [on their download page](http://routeware.dk/download.php).

And there's a description of the features [on the Toolbox 1.07 page](http://routeware.dk/toolbox.php). Look for the Add Nodes feature.

And if you want to have a look at the sourcecode, you can download that from the same site, too